# Oh dear! Can you help me sort this out?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Ring, ring! Before my group can play tonight, we need to get together with you to figure something out.

Our gig is the top space in the region, but now they claim there isn't room for all 16 of us. Can you scope it out?

Then, after that, can you tell us who should stand by whom?

A number of us (four, in fact) are afraid of being observed by the audience, but the rest of us aren't as shy. Hope this is all the info you need!

Hints:

> The four lines above simultaneously describe a common puzzle type and  give the clues necessary to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Should this really be an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle]?

Comment: I believe that this is a "puzzle where the puzzler must deduce what type of puzzle it is." Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Perhaps it's [tag:steganography] - data hidden in otherwise unsuspicious text

Comment: I believe that enigmatic-puzzle more appropriate. To say more would be a bit of a spoiler, but if it's too obtuse, I will add a hint tomorrow.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's just that there's been [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38509779#38509779) over whether people are beginning to 'abuse' the tag

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm pretty sure this is the intended use of the enigmatic-puzzle tag and that it will be clear once someone has figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but i think the answer is

> **15 puzzle**
>
>
>  [image]

there isn't room for all 16 of us

> there are only 15 tiles and one space is kept empty so that the other tiles can be moved

can you tell us who should stand by whom?

> this is basically solving the puzzle, to place the tiles in the right order

A number of us (four, in fact) are afraid of being observed by the audience

> since its a square four tiles are not around the perimeter(as it can be seen in the picture above)

Comment: You got the shape right, but not the correct puzzle type. The items in the square can be determined (hopefully!) by the text in the puzzle.

Comment: It could be a Rota Jigsaw Puzzle with 15 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

My guess (partial solution):

> The group of 16 are chess pieces, in the top row of a chessboard. In which case it would be 8 pawns together, then RKBQKBKR.

Comment: I like the answer! But what are the four that are "afraid of being observed by the audience"?

Comment: Not sure about that - hence the partial solution

Comment: This is clever and fits the second line of the puzzle well, but all four lines of the puzzle will be used in the final solution :) (and it is not a chess related puzzle)